# chamfering of die ends

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

I was reading about all types of tube drawing process and i wanted to look up some images for better understanding. When i looked at images in different sites most of them had the die ends chamfered at some angle. I tried to find out why this is done but i couldn't.

[image]

If anybody can help me that would be great ! Thanks

Comment: Sharp corners are more likely to crack. Not likely to affect the product at the die exit .  Sharp corners ( internal or external) are generally avoided in dies unless necessary.

Comment: @blacksmith37   okay thanks for the help !